# MySQL Trigger Replace Accented/Unwanted Variables using an Array of Values

Tags: mysql, sql, foreach, triggers, mariadb

I am trying to create a **MySQL trigger** to change a string into a proper filename. I would like to replace accented/strange variables with the equivalent counterparts *(Qu**é**bec -> Quebec)*

I have an array (I found) with all the characters with the equivalent letter that I would like to replace with:

```
{"Á":"A","Ă":"A","Ắ":"A","Ặ":"A","Ằ":"A","Ẳ":"A","Ẵ":"A","Ǎ":"A","Â":"A","Ấ":"A","Ậ":"A","Ầ":"A","Ẩ":"A","Ẫ":"A","Ä":"A","Ǟ":"A","Ȧ":"A","Ǡ":"A","Ạ":"A","Ȁ":"A","À":"A","Ả":"A","Ȃ":"A","Ā":"A","Ą":"A","Å":"A","Ǻ":"A","Ḁ":"A","Ⱥ":"A","Ã":"A","Ꜳ":"AA","Æ":"AE","Ǽ":"AE","Ǣ":"AE","Ꜵ":"AO","Ꜷ":"AU","Ꜹ":"AV","Ꜻ":"AV","Ꜽ":"AY","Ḃ":"B","Ḅ":"B","Ɓ":"B","Ḇ":"B","Ƀ":"B","Ƃ":"B","Ć":"C","Č":"C","Ç":"C","Ḉ":"C","Ĉ":"C","Ċ":"C","Ƈ":"C","Ȼ":"C","Ď":"D","Ḑ":"D","Ḓ":"D","Ḋ":"D","Ḍ":"D","Ɗ":"D","Ḏ":"D","ǲ":"D","ǅ":"D","Đ":"D","Ƌ":"D","Ǳ":"DZ","Ǆ":"DZ","É":"E","Ĕ":"E","Ě":"E","Ȩ":"E","Ḝ":"E","Ê":"E","Ế":"E","Ệ":"E","Ề":"E","Ể":"E","Ễ":"E","Ḙ":"E","Ë":"E","Ė":"E","Ẹ":"E","Ȅ":"E","È":"E","Ẻ":"E","Ȇ":"E","Ē":"E","Ḗ":"E","Ḕ":"E","Ę":"E","Ɇ":"E","Ẽ":"E","Ḛ":"E","Ꝫ":"ET","Ḟ":"F","Ƒ":"F","Ǵ":"G","Ğ":"G","Ǧ":"G","Ģ":"G","Ĝ":"G","Ġ":"G","Ɠ":"G","Ḡ":"G","Ǥ":"G","Ḫ":"H","Ȟ":"H","Ḩ":"H","Ĥ":"H","Ⱨ":"H","Ḧ":"H","Ḣ":"H","Ḥ":"H","Ħ":"H","Í":"I","Ĭ":"I","Ǐ":"I","Î":"I","Ï":"I","Ḯ":"I","İ":"I","Ị":"I","Ȉ":"I","Ì":"I","Ỉ":"I","Ȋ":"I","Ī":"I","Į":"I","Ɨ":"I","Ĩ":"I","Ḭ":"I","Ꝺ":"D","Ꝼ":"F","Ᵹ":"G","Ꞃ":"R","Ꞅ":"S","Ꞇ":"T","Ꝭ":"IS","Ĵ":"J","Ɉ":"J","Ḱ":"K","Ǩ":"K","Ķ":"K","Ⱪ":"K","Ꝃ":"K","Ḳ":"K","Ƙ":"K","Ḵ":"K","Ꝁ":"K","Ꝅ":"K","Ĺ":"L","Ƚ":"L","Ľ":"L","Ļ":"L","Ḽ":"L","Ḷ":"L","Ḹ":"L","Ⱡ":"L","Ꝉ":"L","Ḻ":"L","Ŀ":"L","Ɫ":"L","ǈ":"L","Ł":"L","Ǉ":"LJ","Ḿ":"M","Ṁ":"M","Ṃ":"M","Ɱ":"M","Ń":"N","Ň":"N","Ņ":"N","Ṋ":"N","Ṅ":"N","Ṇ":"N","Ǹ":"N","Ɲ":"N","Ṉ":"N","Ƞ":"N","ǋ":"N","Ñ":"N","Ǌ":"NJ","Ó":"O","Ŏ":"O","Ǒ":"O","Ô":"O","Ố":"O","Ộ":"O","Ồ":"O","Ổ":"O","Ỗ":"O","Ö":"O","Ȫ":"O","Ȯ":"O","Ȱ":"O","Ọ":"O","Ő":"O","Ȍ":"O","Ò":"O","Ỏ":"O","Ơ":"O","Ớ":"O","Ợ":"O","Ờ":"O","Ở":"O","Ỡ":"O","Ȏ":"O","Ꝋ":"O","Ꝍ":"O","Ō":"O","Ṓ":"O","Ṑ":"O","Ɵ":"O","Ǫ":"O","Ǭ":"O","Ø":"O","Ǿ":"O","Õ":"O","Ṍ":"O","Ṏ":"O","Ȭ":"O","Ƣ":"OI","Ꝏ":"OO","Ɛ":"E","Ɔ":"O","Ȣ":"OU","Ṕ":"P","Ṗ":"P","Ꝓ":"P","Ƥ":"P","Ꝕ":"P","Ᵽ":"P","Ꝑ":"P","Ꝙ":"Q","Ꝗ":"Q","Ŕ":"R","Ř":"R","Ŗ":"R","Ṙ":"R","Ṛ":"R","Ṝ":"R","Ȑ":"R","Ȓ":"R","Ṟ":"R","Ɍ":"R","Ɽ":"R","Ꜿ":"C","Ǝ":"E","Ś":"S","Ṥ":"S","Š":"S","Ṧ":"S","Ş":"S","Ŝ":"S","Ș":"S","Ṡ":"S","Ṣ":"S","Ṩ":"S","Ť":"T","Ţ":"T","Ṱ":"T","Ț":"T","Ⱦ":"T","Ṫ":"T","Ṭ":"T","Ƭ":"T","Ṯ":"T","Ʈ":"T","Ŧ":"T","Ɐ":"A","Ꞁ":"L","Ɯ":"M","Ʌ":"V","Ꜩ":"TZ","Ú":"U","Ŭ":"U","Ǔ":"U","Û":"U","Ṷ":"U","Ü":"U","Ǘ":"U","Ǚ":"U","Ǜ":"U","Ǖ":"U","Ṳ":"U","Ụ":"U","Ű":"U","Ȕ":"U","Ù":"U","Ủ":"U","Ư":"U","Ứ":"U","Ự":"U","Ừ":"U","Ử":"U","Ữ":"U","Ȗ":"U","Ū":"U","Ṻ":"U","Ų":"U","Ů":"U","Ũ":"U","Ṹ":"U","Ṵ":"U","Ꝟ":"V","Ṿ":"V","Ʋ":"V","Ṽ":"V","Ꝡ":"VY","Ẃ":"W","Ŵ":"W","Ẅ":"W","Ẇ":"W","Ẉ":"W","Ẁ":"W","Ⱳ":"W","Ẍ":"X","Ẋ":"X","Ý":"Y","Ŷ":"Y","Ÿ":"Y","Ẏ":"Y","Ỵ":"Y","Ỳ":"Y","Ƴ":"Y","Ỷ":"Y","Ỿ":"Y","Ȳ":"Y","Ɏ":"Y","Ỹ":"Y","Ź":"Z","Ž":"Z","Ẑ":"Z","Ⱬ":"Z","Ż":"Z","Ẓ":"Z","Ȥ":"Z","Ẕ":"Z","Ƶ":"Z","Ĳ":"IJ","Œ":"OE","ᴀ":"A","ᴁ":"AE","ʙ":"B","ᴃ":"B","ᴄ":"C","ᴅ":"D","ᴇ":"E","ꜰ":"F","ɢ":"G","ʛ":"G","ʜ":"H","ɪ":"I","ʁ":"R","ᴊ":"J","ᴋ":"K","ʟ":"L","ᴌ":"L","ᴍ":"M","ɴ":"N","ᴏ":"O","ɶ":"OE","ᴐ":"O","ᴕ":"OU","ᴘ":"P","ʀ":"R","ᴎ":"N","ᴙ":"R","ꜱ":"S","ᴛ":"T","ⱻ":"E","ᴚ":"R","ᴜ":"U","ᴠ":"V","ᴡ":"W","ʏ":"Y","ᴢ":"Z","á":"a","ă":"a","ắ":"a","ặ":"a","ằ":"a","ẳ":"a","ẵ":"a","ǎ":"a","â":"a","ấ":"a","ậ":"a","ầ":"a","ẩ":"a","ẫ":"a","ä":"a","ǟ":"a","ȧ":"a","ǡ":"a","ạ":"a","ȁ":"a","à":"a","ả":"a","ȃ":"a","ā":"a","ą":"a","ᶏ":"a","ẚ":"a","å":"a","ǻ":"a","ḁ":"a","ⱥ":"a","ã":"a","ꜳ":"aa","æ":"ae","ǽ":"ae","ǣ":"ae","ꜵ":"ao","ꜷ":"au","ꜹ":"av","ꜻ":"av","ꜽ":"ay","ḃ":"b","ḅ":"b","ɓ":"b","ḇ":"b","ᵬ":"b","ᶀ":"b","ƀ":"b","ƃ":"b","ɵ":"o","ć":"c","č":"c","ç":"c","ḉ":"c","ĉ":"c","ɕ":"c","ċ":"c","ƈ":"c","ȼ":"c","ď":"d","ḑ":"d","ḓ":"d","ȡ":"d","ḋ":"d","ḍ":"d","ɗ":"d","ᶑ":"d","ḏ":"d","ᵭ":"d","ᶁ":"d","đ":"d","ɖ":"d","ƌ":"d","ı":"i","ȷ":"j","ɟ":"j","ʄ":"j","ǳ":"dz","ǆ":"dz","é":"e","ĕ":"e","ě":"e","ȩ":"e","ḝ":"e","ê":"e","ế":"e","ệ":"e","ề":"e","ể":"e","ễ":"e","ḙ":"e","ë":"e","ė":"e","ẹ":"e","ȅ":"e","è":"e","ẻ":"e","ȇ":"e","ē":"e","ḗ":"e","ḕ":"e","ⱸ":"e","ę":"e","ᶒ":"e","ɇ":"e","ẽ":"e","ḛ":"e","ꝫ":"et","ḟ":"f","ƒ":"f","ᵮ":"f","ᶂ":"f","ǵ":"g","ğ":"g","ǧ":"g","ģ":"g","ĝ":"g","ġ":"g","ɠ":"g","ḡ":"g","ᶃ":"g","ǥ":"g","ḫ":"h","ȟ":"h","ḩ":"h","ĥ":"h","ⱨ":"h","ḧ":"h","ḣ":"h","ḥ":"h","ɦ":"h","ẖ":"h","ħ":"h","ƕ":"hv","í":"i","ĭ":"i","ǐ":"i","î":"i","ï":"i","ḯ":"i","ị":"i","ȉ":"i","ì":"i","ỉ":"i","ȋ":"i","ī":"i","į":"i","ᶖ":"i","ɨ":"i","ĩ":"i","ḭ":"i","ꝺ":"d","ꝼ":"f","ᵹ":"g","ꞃ":"r","ꞅ":"s","ꞇ":"t","ꝭ":"is","ǰ":"j","ĵ":"j","ʝ":"j","ɉ":"j","ḱ":"k","ǩ":"k","ķ":"k","ⱪ":"k","ꝃ":"k","ḳ":"k","ƙ":"k","ḵ":"k","ᶄ":"k","ꝁ":"k","ꝅ":"k","ĺ":"l","ƚ":"l","ɬ":"l","ľ":"l","ļ":"l","ḽ":"l","ȴ":"l","ḷ":"l","ḹ":"l","ⱡ":"l","ꝉ":"l","ḻ":"l","ŀ":"l","ɫ":"l","ᶅ":"l","ɭ":"l","ł":"l","ǉ":"lj","ſ":"s","ẜ":"s","ẛ":"s","ẝ":"s","ḿ":"m","ṁ":"m","ṃ":"m","ɱ":"m","ᵯ":"m","ᶆ":"m","ń":"n","ň":"n","ņ":"n","ṋ":"n","ȵ":"n","ṅ":"n","ṇ":"n","ǹ":"n","ɲ":"n","ṉ":"n","ƞ":"n","ᵰ":"n","ᶇ":"n","ɳ":"n","ñ":"n","ǌ":"nj","ó":"o","ŏ":"o","ǒ":"o","ô":"o","ố":"o","ộ":"o","ồ":"o","ổ":"o","ỗ":"o","ö":"o","ȫ":"o","ȯ":"o","ȱ":"o","ọ":"o","ő":"o","ȍ":"o","ò":"o","ỏ":"o","ơ":"o","ớ":"o","ợ":"o","ờ":"o","ở":"o","ỡ":"o","ȏ":"o","ꝋ":"o","ꝍ":"o","ⱺ":"o","ō":"o","ṓ":"o","ṑ":"o","ǫ":"o","ǭ":"o","ø":"o","ǿ":"o","õ":"o","ṍ":"o","ṏ":"o","ȭ":"o","ƣ":"oi","ꝏ":"oo","ɛ":"e","ᶓ":"e","ɔ":"o","ᶗ":"o","ȣ":"ou","ṕ":"p","ṗ":"p","ꝓ":"p","ƥ":"p","ᵱ":"p","ᶈ":"p","ꝕ":"p","ᵽ":"p","ꝑ":"p","ꝙ":"q","ʠ":"q","ɋ":"q","ꝗ":"q","ŕ":"r","ř":"r","ŗ":"r","ṙ":"r","ṛ":"r","ṝ":"r","ȑ":"r","ɾ":"r","ᵳ":"r","ȓ":"r","ṟ":"r","ɼ":"r","ᵲ":"r","ᶉ":"r","ɍ":"r","ɽ":"r","ↄ":"c","ꜿ":"c","ɘ":"e","ɿ":"r","ś":"s","ṥ":"s","š":"s","ṧ":"s","ş":"s","ŝ":"s","ș":"s","ṡ":"s","ṣ":"s","ṩ":"s","ʂ":"s","ᵴ":"s","ᶊ":"s","ȿ":"s","ɡ":"g","ᴑ":"o","ᴓ":"o","ᴝ":"u","ť":"t","ţ":"t","ṱ":"t","ț":"t","ȶ":"t","ẗ":"t","ⱦ":"t","ṫ":"t","ṭ":"t","ƭ":"t","ṯ":"t","ᵵ":"t","ƫ":"t","ʈ":"t","ŧ":"t","ᵺ":"th","ɐ":"a","ᴂ":"ae","ǝ":"e","ᵷ":"g","ɥ":"h","ʮ":"h","ʯ":"h","ᴉ":"i","ʞ":"k","ꞁ":"l","ɯ":"m","ɰ":"m","ᴔ":"oe","ɹ":"r","ɻ":"r","ɺ":"r","ⱹ":"r","ʇ":"t","ʌ":"v","ʍ":"w","ʎ":"y","ꜩ":"tz","ú":"u","ŭ":"u","ǔ":"u","û":"u","ṷ":"u","ü":"u","ǘ":"u","ǚ":"u","ǜ":"u","ǖ":"u","ṳ":"u","ụ":"u","ű":"u","ȕ":"u","ù":"u","ủ":"u","ư":"u","ứ":"u","ự":"u","ừ":"u","ử":"u","ữ":"u","ȗ":"u","ū":"u","ṻ":"u","ų":"u","ᶙ":"u","ů":"u","ũ":"u","ṹ":"u","ṵ":"u","ᵫ":"ue","ꝸ":"um","ⱴ":"v","ꝟ":"v","ṿ":"v","ʋ":"v","ᶌ":"v","ⱱ":"v","ṽ":"v","ꝡ":"vy","ẃ":"w","ŵ":"w","ẅ":"w","ẇ":"w","ẉ":"w","ẁ":"w","ⱳ":"w","ẘ":"w","ẍ":"x","ẋ":"x","ᶍ":"x","ý":"y","ŷ":"y","ÿ":"y","ẏ":"y","ỵ":"y","ỳ":"y","ƴ":"y","ỷ":"y","ỿ":"y","ȳ":"y","ẙ":"y","ɏ":"y","ỹ":"y","ź":"z","ž":"z","ẑ":"z","ʑ":"z","ⱬ":"z","ż":"z","ẓ":"z","ȥ":"z","ẕ":"z","ᵶ":"z","ᶎ":"z","ʐ":"z","ƶ":"z","ɀ":"z","ﬀ":"ff","ﬃ":"ffi","ﬄ":"ffl","ﬁ":"fi","ﬂ":"fl","ĳ":"ij","œ":"oe","ﬆ":"st","ₐ":"a","ₑ":"e","ᵢ":"i","ⱼ":"j","ₒ":"o","ᵣ":"r","ᵤ":"u","ᵥ":"v","ₓ":"x"};
```

Is there a way to quickly and efficiently do this replace in my MySQL Trigger?

```
SET @STRING = "Québec";
FOR EACH ITEM IN ARRAY AS KEY/VALUE
 SET @STRING=REPLACE(@STRING,KEY,VALUE);
END;
```

Or is there a better way to do this? I've tried to change my Encoding/Collation for my column without success.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use arrays directly. But you can work with strings. Change array into string delimited by "," for each key/value pair and further delimited by ":". Then run through string in a while loop.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `sanitize_string`(STRING varchar(255)) RETURNS varchar(255)
begin
 /* set as array as string delimited by a "," for each key/value pair and delimited again by a ":" for each key/value */
 /* key is the unwanted character, value is the wanted character */
 set  @chars="Á:A,Ă:A,Ắ:A,Ặ:A,Ằ:A,Ẳ:A,Ẵ:A,Ǎ:A,Â:A,Ấ:A,Ậ:A,Ầ:A,Ẩ:A,Ẫ:A,Ä:A,Ǟ:A,Ȧ:A,Ǡ:A,Ạ:A,Ȁ:A,À:A,Ả:A,Ȃ:A,Ā:A,Ą:A,Å:A,Ǻ:A,Ḁ:A,Ⱥ:A,Ã:A,Ꜳ:AA,Æ:AE,Ǽ:AE,Ǣ:AE,Ꜵ:AO,Ꜷ:AU,Ꜹ:AV,Ꜻ:AV,Ꜽ:AY,Ḃ:B,Ḅ:B,Ɓ:B,Ḇ:B,Ƀ:B,Ƃ:B,Ć:C,Č:C,Ç:C,Ḉ:C,Ĉ:C,Ċ:C,Ƈ:C,Ȼ:C,Ď:D,Ḑ:D,Ḓ:D,Ḋ:D,Ḍ:D,Ɗ:D,Ḏ:D,ǲ:D,ǅ:D,Đ:D,Ƌ:D,Ǳ:DZ,Ǆ:DZ,É:E,Ĕ:E,Ě:E,Ȩ:E,Ḝ:E,Ê:E,Ế:E,Ệ:E,Ề:E,Ể:E,Ễ:E,Ḙ:E,Ë:E,Ė:E,Ẹ:E,Ȅ:E,È:E,Ẻ:E,Ȇ:E,Ē:E,Ḗ:E,Ḕ:E,Ę:E,Ɇ:E,Ẽ:E,Ḛ:E,Ꝫ:ET,Ḟ:F,Ƒ:F,Ǵ:G,Ğ:G,Ǧ:G,Ģ:G,Ĝ:G,Ġ:G,Ɠ:G,Ḡ:G,Ǥ:G,Ḫ:H,Ȟ:H,Ḩ:H,Ĥ:H,Ⱨ:H,Ḧ:H,Ḣ:H,Ḥ:H,Ħ:H,Í:I,Ĭ:I,Ǐ:I,Î:I,Ï:I,Ḯ:I,İ:I,Ị:I,Ȉ:I,Ì:I,Ỉ:I,Ȋ:I,Ī:I,Į:I,Ɨ:I,Ĩ:I,Ḭ:I,Ꝺ:D,Ꝼ:F,Ᵹ:G,Ꞃ:R,Ꞅ:S,Ꞇ:T,Ꝭ:IS,Ĵ:J,Ɉ:J,Ḱ:K,Ǩ:K,Ķ:K,Ⱪ:K,Ꝃ:K,Ḳ:K,Ƙ:K,Ḵ:K,Ꝁ:K,Ꝅ:K,Ĺ:L,Ƚ:L,Ľ:L,Ļ:L,Ḽ:L,Ḷ:L,Ḹ:L,Ⱡ:L,Ꝉ:L,Ḻ:L,Ŀ:L,Ɫ:L,ǈ:L,Ł:L,Ǉ:LJ,Ḿ:M,Ṁ:M,Ṃ:M,Ɱ:M,Ń:N,Ň:N,Ņ:N,Ṋ:N,Ṅ:N,Ṇ:N,Ǹ:N,Ɲ:N,Ṉ:N,Ƞ:N,ǋ:N,Ñ:N,Ǌ:NJ,Ó:O,Ŏ:O,Ǒ:O,Ô:O,Ố:O,Ộ:O,Ồ:O,Ổ:O,Ỗ:O,Ö:O,Ȫ:O,Ȯ:O,Ȱ:O,Ọ:O,Ő:O,Ȍ:O,Ò:O,Ỏ:O,Ơ:O,Ớ:O,Ợ:O,Ờ:O,Ở:O,Ỡ:O,Ȏ:O,Ꝋ:O,Ꝍ:O,Ō:O,Ṓ:O,Ṑ:O,Ɵ:O,Ǫ:O,Ǭ:O,Ø:O,Ǿ:O,Õ:O,Ṍ:O,Ṏ:O,Ȭ:O,Ƣ:OI,Ꝏ:OO,Ɛ:E,Ɔ:O,Ȣ:OU,Ṕ:P,Ṗ:P,Ꝓ:P,Ƥ:P,Ꝕ:P,Ᵽ:P,Ꝑ:P,Ꝙ:Q,Ꝗ:Q,Ŕ:R,Ř:R,Ŗ:R,Ṙ:R,Ṛ:R,Ṝ:R,Ȑ:R,Ȓ:R,Ṟ:R,Ɍ:R,Ɽ:R,Ꜿ:C,Ǝ:E,Ś:S,Ṥ:S,Š:S,Ṧ:S,Ş:S,Ŝ:S,Ș:S,Ṡ:S,Ṣ:S,Ṩ:S,Ť:T,Ţ:T,Ṱ:T,Ț:T,Ⱦ:T,Ṫ:T,Ṭ:T,Ƭ:T,Ṯ:T,Ʈ:T,Ŧ:T,Ɐ:A,Ꞁ:L,Ɯ:M,Ʌ:V,Ꜩ:TZ,Ú:U,Ŭ:U,Ǔ:U,Û:U,Ṷ:U,Ü:U,Ǘ:U,Ǚ:U,Ǜ:U,Ǖ:U,Ṳ:U,Ụ:U,Ű:U,Ȕ:U,Ù:U,Ủ:U,Ư:U,Ứ:U,Ự:U,Ừ:U,Ử:U,Ữ:U,Ȗ:U,Ū:U,Ṻ:U,Ų:U,Ů:U,Ũ:U,Ṹ:U,Ṵ:U,Ꝟ:V,Ṿ:V,Ʋ:V,Ṽ:V,Ꝡ:VY,Ẃ:W,Ŵ:W,Ẅ:W,Ẇ:W,Ẉ:W,Ẁ:W,Ⱳ:W,Ẍ:X,Ẋ:X,Ý:Y,Ŷ:Y,Ÿ:Y,Ẏ:Y,Ỵ:Y,Ỳ:Y,Ƴ:Y,Ỷ:Y,Ỿ:Y,Ȳ:Y,Ɏ:Y,Ỹ:Y,Ź:Z,Ž:Z,Ẑ:Z,Ⱬ:Z,Ż:Z,Ẓ:Z,Ȥ:Z,Ẕ:Z,Ƶ:Z,Ĳ:IJ,Œ:OE,ᴀ:A,ᴁ:AE,ʙ:B,ᴃ:B,ᴄ:C,ᴅ:D,ᴇ:E,ꜰ:F,ɢ:G,ʛ:G,ʜ:H,ɪ:I,ʁ:R,ᴊ:J,ᴋ:K,ʟ:L,ᴌ:L,ᴍ:M,ɴ:N,ᴏ:O,ɶ:OE,ᴐ:O,ᴕ:OU,ᴘ:P,ʀ:R,ᴎ:N,ᴙ:R,ꜱ:S,ᴛ:T,ⱻ:E,ᴚ:R,ᴜ:U,ᴠ:V,ᴡ:W,ʏ:Y,ᴢ:Z,á:a,ă:a,ắ:a,ặ:a,ằ:a,ẳ:a,ẵ:a,ǎ:a,â:a,ấ:a,ậ:a,ầ:a,ẩ:a,ẫ:a,ä:a,ǟ:a,ȧ:a,ǡ:a,ạ:a,ȁ:a,à:a,ả:a,ȃ:a,ā:a,ą:a,ᶏ:a,ẚ:a,å:a,ǻ:a,ḁ:a,ⱥ:a,ã:a,ꜳ:aa,æ:ae,ǽ:ae,ǣ:ae,ꜵ:ao,ꜷ:au,ꜹ:av,ꜻ:av,ꜽ:ay,ḃ:b,ḅ:b,ɓ:b,ḇ:b,ᵬ:b,ᶀ:b,ƀ:b,ƃ:b,ɵ:o,ć:c,č:c,ç:c,ḉ:c,ĉ:c,ɕ:c,ċ:c,ƈ:c,ȼ:c,ď:d,ḑ:d,ḓ:d,ȡ:d,ḋ:d,ḍ:d,ɗ:d,ᶑ:d,ḏ:d,ᵭ:d,ᶁ:d,đ:d,ɖ:d,ƌ:d,ı:i,ȷ:j,ɟ:j,ʄ:j,ǳ:dz,ǆ:dz,é:e,ĕ:e,ě:e,ȩ:e,ḝ:e,ê:e,ế:e,ệ:e,ề:e,ể:e,ễ:e,ḙ:e,ë:e,ė:e,ẹ:e,ȅ:e,è:e,ẻ:e,ȇ:e,ē:e,ḗ:e,ḕ:e,ⱸ:e,ę:e,ᶒ:e,ɇ:e,ẽ:e,ḛ:e,ꝫ:et,ḟ:f,ƒ:f,ᵮ:f,ᶂ:f,ǵ:g,ğ:g,ǧ:g,ģ:g,ĝ:g,ġ:g,ɠ:g,ḡ:g,ᶃ:g,ǥ:g,ḫ:h,ȟ:h,ḩ:h,ĥ:h,ⱨ:h,ḧ:h,ḣ:h,ḥ:h,ɦ:h,ẖ:h,ħ:h,ƕ:hv,í:i,ĭ:i,ǐ:i,î:i,ï:i,ḯ:i,ị:i,ȉ:i,ì:i,ỉ:i,ȋ:i,ī:i,į:i,ᶖ:i,ɨ:i,ĩ:i,ḭ:i,ꝺ:d,ꝼ:f,ᵹ:g,ꞃ:r,ꞅ:s,ꞇ:t,ꝭ:is,ǰ:j,ĵ:j,ʝ:j,ɉ:j,ḱ:k,ǩ:k,ķ:k,ⱪ:k,ꝃ:k,ḳ:k,ƙ:k,ḵ:k,ᶄ:k,ꝁ:k,ꝅ:k,ĺ:l,ƚ:l,ɬ:l,ľ:l,ļ:l,ḽ:l,ȴ:l,ḷ:l,ḹ:l,ⱡ:l,ꝉ:l,ḻ:l,ŀ:l,ɫ:l,ᶅ:l,ɭ:l,ł:l,ǉ:lj,ſ:s,ẜ:s,ẛ:s,ẝ:s,ḿ:m,ṁ:m,ṃ:m,ɱ:m,ᵯ:m,ᶆ:m,ń:n,ň:n,ņ:n,ṋ:n,ȵ:n,ṅ:n,ṇ:n,ǹ:n,ɲ:n,ṉ:n,ƞ:n,ᵰ:n,ᶇ:n,ɳ:n,ñ:n,ǌ:nj,ó:o,ŏ:o,ǒ:o,ô:o,ố:o,ộ:o,ồ:o,ổ:o,ỗ:o,ö:o,ȫ:o,ȯ:o,ȱ:o,ọ:o,ő:o,ȍ:o,ò:o,ỏ:o,ơ:o,ớ:o,ợ:o,ờ:o,ở:o,ỡ:o,ȏ:o,ꝋ:o,ꝍ:o,ⱺ:o,ō:o,ṓ:o,ṑ:o,ǫ:o,ǭ:o,ø:o,ǿ:o,õ:o,ṍ:o,ṏ:o,ȭ:o,ƣ:oi,ꝏ:oo,ɛ:e,ᶓ:e,ɔ:o,ᶗ:o,ȣ:ou,ṕ:p,ṗ:p,ꝓ:p,ƥ:p,ᵱ:p,ᶈ:p,ꝕ:p,ᵽ:p,ꝑ:p,ꝙ:q,ʠ:q,ɋ:q,ꝗ:q,ŕ:r,ř:r,ŗ:r,ṙ:r,ṛ:r,ṝ:r,ȑ:r,ɾ:r,ᵳ:r,ȓ:r,ṟ:r,ɼ:r,ᵲ:r,ᶉ:r,ɍ:r,ɽ:r,ↄ:c,ꜿ:c,ɘ:e,ɿ:r,ś:s,ṥ:s,š:s,ṧ:s,ş:s,ŝ:s,ș:s,ṡ:s,ṣ:s,ṩ:s,ʂ:s,ᵴ:s,ᶊ:s,ȿ:s,ɡ:g,ᴑ:o,ᴓ:o,ᴝ:u,ť:t,ţ:t,ṱ:t,ț:t,ȶ:t,ẗ:t,ⱦ:t,ṫ:t,ṭ:t,ƭ:t,ṯ:t,ᵵ:t,ƫ:t,ʈ:t,ŧ:t,ᵺ:th,ɐ:a,ᴂ:ae,ǝ:e,ᵷ:g,ɥ:h,ʮ:h,ʯ:h,ᴉ:i,ʞ:k,ꞁ:l,ɯ:m,ɰ:m,ᴔ:oe,ɹ:r,ɻ:r,ɺ:r,ⱹ:r,ʇ:t,ʌ:v,ʍ:w,ʎ:y,ꜩ:tz,ú:u,ŭ:u,ǔ:u,û:u,ṷ:u,ü:u,ǘ:u,ǚ:u,ǜ:u,ǖ:u,ṳ:u,ụ:u,ű:u,ȕ:u,ù:u,ủ:u,ư:u,ứ:u,ự:u,ừ:u,ử:u,ữ:u,ȗ:u,ū:u,ṻ:u,ų:u,ᶙ:u,ů:u,ũ:u,ṹ:u,ṵ:u,ᵫ:ue,ꝸ:um,ⱴ:v,ꝟ:v,ṿ:v,ʋ:v,ᶌ:v,ⱱ:v,ṽ:v,ꝡ:vy,ẃ:w,ŵ:w,ẅ:w,ẇ:w,ẉ:w,ẁ:w,ⱳ:w,ẘ:w,ẍ:x,ẋ:x,ᶍ:x,ý:y,ŷ:y,ÿ:y,ẏ:y,ỵ:y,ỳ:y,ƴ:y,ỷ:y,ỿ:y,ȳ:y,ẙ:y,ɏ:y,ỹ:y,ź:z,ž:z,ẑ:z,ʑ:z,ⱬ:z,ż:z,ẓ:z,ȥ:z,ẕ:z,ᵶ:z,ᶎ:z,ʐ:z,ƶ:z,ɀ:z,ﬀ:ff,ﬃ:ffi,ﬄ:ffl,ﬁ:fi,ﬂ:fl,ĳ:ij,œ:oe,ﬆ:st,ₐ:a,ₑ:e,ᵢ:i,ⱼ:j,ₒ:o,ᵣ:r,ᵤ:u,ᵥ:v,ₓ:x";
 /* while string contains a ",", keep looping */
 while(locate(',',@chars)>0)
 do
  /* get first key/value pair */
  set @pair=substring_index(@chars,',',1);
  /* get the key */
  set @key=substring_index(@pair,':',1);
  /* get the value */
  set @value=replace(@pair,@key+':','');
  /* cut the key/value pair out of the array string for next loop */
  set @chars=substring(@chars,locate(',',@chars)+1);
  /* if key exists, replace with value */
  set STRING=replace(STRING,@key,@value);
 end while;
 return STRING;
end;
```

Where:

```
return sanitize_string("Québec");
/* returns "Quebec" */
```